# Keras VGGnet Pretrained Model Variable Sized Input

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, pre-trained-model, vgg-net

I want to extract features of a 368x368 sized image with VGG pretrained model. According to documentation VGGnet accepts 224x224 sized images. Is there a way to give variable sized input to Keras VGG?

Here is my code:

```
# VGG Feature Extraction
x_train = np.random.randint(0, 255, (100, 224, 224, 3))
base_model = VGG19(weights='imagenet')
modelVGG = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=base_model.get_layer('block4_conv2').output)
block4_conv2_features = modelVGG.predict(x_train)
```

Edited code (It works!)

```
# VGG Feature Extraction
x_train = np.random.randint(0, 255, (100, 368, 368, 3))
base_model = VGG19(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
modelVGG = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=base_model.get_layer('block4_conv2').output)
block4_conv2_features = modelVGG.predict(x_train)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The input size affects the number of neurons in the fully-connected (`Dense`) layers. So you need to create your own fully-connected layers.

Call VGG19 with `include_top=False` to remove the fully-connected layers and then add them yourself. Check [this code](https://gist.github.com/fchollet/7eb39b44eb9e16e59632d25fb3119975#file-classifier_from_little_data_script_3-py-L59-L67) for reference.